# nodeMCU - when DC is active on pin the do this

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, nodemcu

i have a nodeMCU v3(esp8266)
and what i want is: when i send  DC 5v or 3v to a pin=**D1** (idk if its possible to send 5v directly to pin) then to activate the **D0** for 20Seconds

like this:

```
 if (D1==Sends signal){
    digitalWrite(pinD0, HIGH);
      delay(20000);  //pinD0 is active for 20 seconds

  }else{
     digitalWrite(pinD0, LOW);

  }
```

Comment: you can connect 5v to the gpio through a red LED or a level shifter, then just use digitalRead()

Comment: my question is:
if i can ping a D0 pin  from another device  and nodemcu to activate D1 pin for 20 seconds if recived ping(signal) in pin D0